# Как из строки сделать html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

из базы данных я получаю строку вида:

```
[@nickname](1) текст для примера
```

После на каждой я вызываю:

```
     const createLink = (textComment: string) =>
 textComment.replace(/@\[([^()]+)\]\(([^()]+)\)/g, '<a href=/user/$2>$1</a>');
```

Данная операция заменяет в тексте все ники и id на url к странице, но вместо ссылки я получаю ссылку обычным текстом:

```
<a href=/user/1>@nickname</a> текст для примера
```

Вызов:

```
<div>
    {createLink(text)}
</div>
```

Как сделать так что-бы была ссылка, а не обычный текст, о рендере html знаю, но мне нужно только ссылку вставлять, а не возможность обрабатывать html

Использую react

Edit: он заменяет на ссылку данный шаблон где бы он не находился перед, после или посередине текста

Answer (score 1):

Текст с тегами не превратится в html просто от вставки внутрь блока, нужно использовать атрибут [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: createLink(text) }} />
```